# Problemas con archivos css y js Django 2.0.7 y Python 3.7

Tags: django

No logro cargar mis archivos estaticos css y js:

```
Mi settings :


import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

#PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '&zd^9_h4fa9s4e%ylo6qqjfi2dmya*^7)#7bdvb6-t+b%8=#qr'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #'django-bootstrap',
    #'django-jquery',
    'apps.adopcion',
    'apps.mascota',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'refugio.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        #'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        #OK, ME FUNCIONO CON LA DIRECCION
        'DIRS':['C:/Users/JORGE IVAN SIERRA/Proyectos_PY37/PP37DJANGO_REF2/refugio/refugio/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'refugio.wsgi.application'

"""TEMPLATES = [{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
}]"""

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'refug2',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '12345',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS=[os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')]
```

>

```
Mi index html:

        {% load static %}
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="es">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">

            {% block extrastatic %}
            {% endblock %}

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
            <title>{%block title %} Document {% endblock %}</title>

        <body>
        <div class="container">

            {% block navbar %}
                <div class="bs-docs-section clearfix">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="bs-component">
                                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <div class="navbar-header">
                                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                            <li class="dropdown">
                                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="
                                                dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Mascotas
                                                <span class="caret" ></span></a>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                    <li><a href="#">Registrar</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Listar</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="dropdown">
                                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="
                                                dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                                Adopciones<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                    <li><a href="#">Solicitar</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Listar solicitudes</a></li>
                                                <ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="http://actualicese.com"
                                            onclick="pageTractor._link(this.href); return false;">
                                            Actualicese.com</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="dropdown">
                                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="
                                                dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                            Opciones<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                    <li><a href="#">Salir</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endblock %}

            {% block content %}
            <h4> Bloque de contenido  </h4>
            {% endblock %}

            {% block footer %}
            {% endblock %}

        </div>
            <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
            <script  src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>


            {% block extrajs %}
            {% endblock %}

        </body>
        </html>
```

>
Alguna orientación, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que daba la configuracion seria algo asi:

**settings.py**

```
 #agrega esto al final de tu settings.py

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/static/',
]
```

ahora en tu template(pagina.html), es muy importante el tag:

```
<!--ASI DECLARAS EL STATIC-->
{% load staticfiles %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Si te fijas la declaracion va antes que cualquier tag, otra cosa es staticfiles no solo static:

```
 {% load staticfiles %}
```

Te sugiero que revises la documentacion oficial:
[Documentacion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/)

Espero te sirva y suerte

Comment: Amigo, ya hice la prueba pero solo muestra el Hello world, (no muestra los temas  css y js), estoy con pycharm community 2018.1  este es el error por consola:      [10/Jul/2018 16:56:02] "GET /mascota/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2228
[10/Jul/2018 16:56:02] "GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1681
[10/Jul/2018 16:56:02] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1687
[10/Jul/2018 16:56:02] "GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1681

Comment: No quiere cargar los estaticos

Comment: Tengo la duda si es por el IDE Pycharm community